# Azure Web Job: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.5.0.0

Tags: f#, msbuild, azure-webjobs

I have some Azure Web Jobs that I am upgrading to the latest version of FSharp.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 to create FSharp Console apps that get run in the web job. Here is the project's properties:

[image]

> When I run the job, I am seeing this in the log: [09/21/2018 16:01:39
>
> > 99459b: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.5.0.0,
> >     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> >     dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried adding this in the .config and it did not help:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

When I change the .config to this

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.4.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I get this error

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it by unload this FSharp project and removing this line:

```
<TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.4.3.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>
```

Then the project page looks like this:
[image]

I then went to references and deleted the broken 4.4.3 reference
[image]

I then added a reference to the project (old fashion way) and navigated to the nuget folder (users/.nuget/FSharp/etc...) and made that reference.  Marked it "Copy Always" and it worked